# Навигация laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Начинаю изучать laravel. Встал вопрос как реализовать вывод элементов навигации из бд в шаблон?

Comment: А как вы храните элементы навигации в бд?

Comment: в таблице navigations есть строки со столбцами id,ru,en,parent_id.